# Method return ViewModel from 2 tables using join and where clause

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I'm working on one method, I have two models, Artist and Album, I want to show all the Albums belonging to an Artist according to the `ArtistID` field belonging to Artist, with information of both models Artist and Album, that's why I created a ViewModel. I'm working in a separate class named Operations to work with my methods separated from Models and Controllers, I'm working with lambda expressions, I don't how to set the "where" condition for `ArtistID = id` parameter. Do you know how to do this?

These are the Models:

```
public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Artist name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public int AlbumID { get; set; }
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public int ArtistID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString ="{0: dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name ="Date created")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

}
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
public class ArtistAlbumVM
{
    public int ArtistAge { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistLastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime AlbumDate { get; set; }
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the methdo I'm talking about, I don't know how to set the "where" condition `ArtistID = id`:

```
public class Operations
{
    MusicStoreDbContext db = new MusicStoreDbContext();
    public List<ArtistAlbumVM> GetAlbumsByArtist(int id)
    {
        var list = db.Albums.Join(db.Artists, al => al.ArtistID, ar => ar.ArtistID,
            (al, ar) => new ArtistAlbumVM {
                ArtistAge = ar.Age,
                ArtistName =ar.Name,
                ArtistLastName = ar.LastName,
                AlbumDate = al.DateCreated,
                AlbumName = al.AlbumName
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ `where` clause.

```
public List<ArtistAlbumVM> GetAlbumsByArtist(int id)
{
  return db.Albums.Where(s=>s.ArtistId==id)
                  .Select(x=> new ArtistAlbumVm 
                         { 
                             ArtistAge = x.Artist.Age,
                             ArtistName =x.Artist.Name,
                             ArtistLastName = x.Artist.LastName,
                             AlbumDate = x.DateCreated,
                             AlbumName = x.AlbumName
                          }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: @Reddy To limit the result, you can use [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) method to provide a where clause. The main part of answer is here `db.Albums.Where(s=>s.ArtistID==id)`. Then if you have a relation between `Album` and `Artist`, you don't need to use `Join` method and it's enough to get information about an artist from `Artist` property of an `Album`. Otherwise you can use `Join` as you did in your question.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes now I undertood the logic. I model already has the property . And its not my question :p

Comment: @Reddy Yes the model contains navigation property and so the OP  - not you ;) - doesn't need a `Join`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, and the rest thanks!! I did it like RezaAghaei told me, and it works!! I just wanted to use a join, I know that without using a join it would be simpler and works too!

Comment: @Reddy That`s right Reddy, it was overlooked I did it using the join clause  and works! I know that there is not need to use a join clause because Album contains a field already named ArtistID!